# peewee playhouse.flask_utils import object_list appear nothing in the home page

Tags: python-3.x, peewee, flask-peewee

I am trying to use peewee flask utils but I dont know what's wrong. It doesn't show anything.

Here is the code:

backend:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdPoU.png

browser display: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PThzr.png

html code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQqah.png

Comment: Please post the actual code, and not pictures of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you had bothered to read the docs, you would have seen that the context variable is named `object_list`.

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#object_list

You've written `for article in article` which makes absolutely **no sense**.

You should write `for article in object_list`